# How to display file names from a folder

Tags: php, file

I'm using this script to display all the images in a folder, but I can't figure out how to get each image's file name to display underneath it. Any suggestions?

```
<?php

$dirname = "images";
$images = scandir($dirname);
$ignore = Array(".", "..", "otherfiletoignore");

foreach($images as $curimg){
    if (!in_array($curimg, $ignore)) {
        echo "<img src='images/$curimg' /><br />\n";
    }
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
echo "<img src='images/$curimg' /><br />$curimg<br />\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think nickf's suggestion is the simplest thing you can do achieve what you want without any css or complex structure..

Comment: If you aren't answering the question, then comment (when you have enough rep) all these extra answers pollute the question.

Comment: It's a pain that you can't comment as soon as you join the site.  If you ask a question you'll get enough rep pretty quickly though.